# Firebase Stroage Image Download , Upload is not working in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Currently i'm working with several application that connected with firebase. But unfortunately, i'm unable to upload image or download image by using download link in android.
What are the main problem ?
**My Project was working good before 30-12-2019.**
There is no changed in source code or firebase privacy policy.
But why suddenly i faced this type of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: so what you have done for ? please explain more with your code.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Kanazariya i try to connect with firebase author, but one day gone ,there is no reply.

Comment: @PratikButani my app already in playstore. and there have some user. i'm sure my code is ok.

Comment: So whats wrong going on?

Comment: @PratikButani suddenly , image is not download or upload. i used Glide library for view the image in android. everything was ok.

Comment: its happens suddenly. my code is 100% ok. even i can't see the preview of image in my firebase console .

Comment: There are Upload and Download Operations Limit for Firebase Storage and GB Download limit. Please see your Usage limit

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said, the first problem that comes to my mind is that you have reached the limit of the Spark plan in Firebase https://firebase.google.com/pricing) or the Flame plan also limited.

If the problem is not about this limitation, you just should take a look at the error message in your callback :

```
 uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
             Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: the error is " + e.getMessage());
       }
 });
```

If there are no errors here, the problem may come from the content itself that is "empty" but without your code it's hard to tell. And if you think the problem comes from firebase, feel free to ask the support team directly.